# Redirect_to on Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test it I get redirect when I pass a object with nil field and I'm getting the error:

```
Failure/Error: }.to assert_redirected_to close_path(@call)
     MiniTest::Assertion:
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

Here's what I did:

```
describe "#Close" do
    before(:each) { @call = FactoryGirl.create(:call) }


    it 'successful closes a call' do
      get :close, {:id => @call.to_param}, valid_session
      response.status.should eq 200
    end


    it "redirects to #close if there's no service described" do
      expect {
        put :done, {:id => @call.to_param,
                    :call => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:call, {:service => nil})},
            valid_session
      }.to assert_redirected_to close_path(@call)
    end
  end
```

The controller:

```
# GET /calls/1/close
  def close
    @call = Call.find(params[:id])
  end


  # PUTS /calls/done
  def done
    respond_to do |format|
      if @call.update(call_params) && @call.service != nil
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Chamada ##{@call.id} foi fechado.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :action => :close, :id => @call.id }
        format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Why it's always getting 200? Does anyone know??

Comment: Your comment on method say "# POST", but your method is PUT. Please verify your routes, is this a PUT path or POST path?

Comment: @BillyChan Thanks its a Puts, I am kinda new to the restfullest stuff. i still kinda live in a GET and POST kinda work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do something like this

```
it "redirects to #close if there's no service described" do
  put :done, {:id => @call.to_param, :call => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:call, :service => nil)}, valid_session
  response.should_be redirected
end
```

Comment: Using a hash as a second argument to `attributes_for` as the OP did is fine. There is no need for the change you indicated.

Answer (score 1):

If `#done` in question covered full code in your app, a response of 200 is expected.

In `#done`, the code dose nothing. It instructs how to respond with `@call` but there is no creation of `@call` at all :) So, nothing happens, 200 returned.

To fix, find `@call` at first in `#done`, like

```
def done
  @call = Call.find(params[:id]) # example code
  respond_to do |format|
  # .....
```